# ext4 partition on 2TB HDD gone and replaced with Windows FAT12 partition

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, pop-os

Recently my computer's PSU died. I am not aware how exactly this happened, but I restored my computer's functionality. I run PopOS 22.04 LTS Linux, and my OS also became unbootable. I repaired it with a bootable USB. When booting in though, I discovered my 2TB Data HDD is also gone.

Its partitions have been replaced with nearly 2TB of ''Unallocated Space'' and a FAT12 Windows partition of 18MB (I forgot the actual name it had, but I think it was something like ''Windows Disk Management''). I did boot into Windows once on accident before repairing Linux as I had a dual-boot setup, I don't know if Windows did anything to it.

My previous partition was a ext4 partition of 2TB, nothing else. It was full of data, and I think that data is still there. What I've tried since is to (perhaps foolishly, I know nothing about this) add a partition, but upon seeing I had to format the partition to have it be functional I stopped. I also tried testdisk, which finds a bunch of old Linux partitions tagged [Data] but ultimately fails when it reports that the partitions are too big to fit on the disk. The partitions have the notice ''this partition ends aftrer the disk limits.''. Here is a hastebin of my testdisk log file: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ahetuwuquv.yaml

Is there any way I can recover my files, or get testdisk to be able to recover my partition or read the files? Thanks in advance, and please let me know if I need to add any logs or information.

Comment: If you find no solutions please give R-Studio Undelete a try, it's the best data recovery software in my experience: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000 A word of caution: undeleted files need to be recovered onto a new device/partition, never written to the same partition where they reside.

Comment: I don't think this would help me sadly because the partition is not functional at this time. To do so it tells me to format that part of the drive which I really don't want to do knowing there is still data in there. I need to recover the partition not the files in it.

Comment: R-Studio Undelete works with raw data and can discover deleted/overwritten partitions as well.

Comment: With no other options I could find, I tried the software and it found & recovered pretty much everything with the exception of like 3 or 4 filenames. Amazing stuff, thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: R-Studio was not able to recover the file hierarchy. I ended up with Hetman partition recovery. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use R-Studio for Linux to recover my drives. I purchased another 2TB to move them onto, and to later use as a RAID 1 array. The software was amazingly able to find all my files with the exception of a few filenames. I guess recovering through TestDisk would've been possible but I am not knowledgeable enough to do so, and R-Studio greatly simplified this process for me.